# Dependency Injection with nodejs: some ideas?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

I'm coding a webapp API using nodejs and I have some situations that I don't know how to proceed.
Admin app can activate modules that change default algorithm behavior. So, I have to inject some logic inside a code block, for example.
I don't know how to do it cause I think that just inserting an `if` clause checking if "A" module is activated would be a good idea. Maybe dependency injection tools are more than I need...
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I would go read the posting rules for stack overflow, your question does not at all follow the posting guidelines.

secondly, all functions in javascript are first class objects that can be passed as arguments. DI is built into the very nature of JS. I would start by with using callback functions to meet your needs.

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/